# Item added to ObservableCollection is successfull but still throws exception

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

``I am utterly confused on why I am getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException occurred
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     Source=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP
>     StackTrace:
>          at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsBasePlatformServices.get_IsInvokeRequired()
>          at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.WeakNotifyProxy.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
>          at ViewModels.ScanBadgesViewModel.Add(BadgeScan result)
>     InnerException:

The error results from the following line:

`EmployeeIds.Add(badge.EmployeeId)`

**NOTE:**
This error is observed on a Xamarin.Forms  Windows 10 Universal app (Preview).

If I comment out the ListView element inside the XAML, then I no longer receive the null exception.

If I only comment out the ItemTemplate of the ListView, then I still observe the null exception.

**XAML:**

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpacing="3" Grid.ColumnSpacing="3" BackgroundColor="Silver">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeIds}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployeeId}"
                  BackgroundColor="Black">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Yellow" XAlign="Start" />
                </ViewCell.View>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </Grid>
```

**ViewModel Property:**

```
        ObservableCollection<EmployeeId> _employeeIds = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeId>();
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeId> EmployeeIds
        {
            get { return _employeeIds; }
            set
            {
                if (_employeeIds != value)
                {
                    _employeeIds = value;
                    OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Entities:**

```
    public class EmployeeId
    {
        public EmployeeId(string employeeId) { Value = employeeId; }

        public string Value { get; }
    }

    public class BadgeScan
    {
        public BadgeScan(string employeeId) { EmployeeId = new EmployeeId(employeeId); }

        public BadgeScan(BadgeScan source, Predicate<string> validate) : this(source.EmployeeId.Value)
        {
            IsValid = validate.Invoke(source.EmployeeId.Value);
        }

        public EmployeeId EmployeeId { get; }

        public bool IsValid { get; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This line of code alters the behavior of my ObservableCollection.Add operation:

```
var administeredScan = new BadgeScan(result, validate);
```

The line simply creates a copy of the object.

```
var validate = DependencyManager.Resolve(typeof(Predicate<string>)) as Predicate<string>;

var administeredScan = new BadgeScan(result, validate);
var canAdd = CanAdd(administeredScan) && 
             ScanMode == Entities.ScanMode.Add;

if (canAdd) Add(administeredScan);
break;
```

This still throws an exception even though an item is added to the collection:
`Add(administeredScan);`

However, this succeeds:

```
var result = obj as BadgeScan;
Add(result);
```

So creating a copy of an object to add to my observable fails. But adding the original object succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a Xamarin.Forms bug in regards to Windows Universal Platform (i.e. Windows 10).**

Instead of invoking the Add operation on the ObservableCollection that my UI is data-bound to, I just create a new ObservableCollection for each Add operation and pass in a collection within the constructor.

**Workaround:**

```
_employeeIdsHack.Add(administeredScan.EmployeeId);
EmployeeIds = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeId>(_employeeIdsHack);
```

Comment: I am getting a similar bug in Xamarin.Forms in regards to android development. Except the exception I get is an Out of Range exception when I try to add an item. Using this answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties are read only.  I would change the properties to have a private set

```
        public EmployeeId EmployeeId { get; private set; }

        public bool IsValid { get; private set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second `BadgeScan` constructor doesn't initialize the `EmployeeId` property. In this line:

```
EmployeeIds.Add(badge.EmployeeId);
```

...it would seem you might be adding a `null` object to the collection. That in itself shouldn't be a problem, but you're using `EmployeeId.Value` in a data binding. My guess is the NRE is connected with this.

---

**Update**: @ScottNimrod says it's a Xamarin bug, in which case the NRE might not be connected with this after all. Even so: Is the non-setting of the `EmployeeId` intentional?